# Is it possible to disable a control but still receive events for that control?

Tags: c#, winforms

In windows forms I have a simple TextBox:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Text = "text" };
textBox.Enabled = false;
textBox.MouseEnter += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("MOUSE ENTERED"); // this never fires if the control is disabled.
};
```

I want to disable the users ability to interact with the control and I want the control to be styled as a disabled control. But I also want to receive `MouseEnter`,`MouseLeave`, and `Click` events from the control so that I can change the background cover of the control on hover and respond to clicks on the control.

But as I have just discovered if you disable a windows forms control it disabled the events as well. I know with some effort I can accomplish the same thing by checking mouse coordinates globally but it would be a lot nicer if I could just have it disabled but still receive events for it. Is that possible?

Comment: May be you want `textBox` be `textBox.ReadOnly = true;` (instead of `Enabled = false;`)?

Comment: Annoyingly, it still lets you put the cursor in the textbox. It just doesn't let you type. It also doesn't have the disabled styles when you do that. Actually a Label might work too so long as it looks more or less the same. I'm trying that now. I'd still prefer to just receive the event on a TextBox though.

Comment: meh, a Label with `AutoSize=true` and `BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle` is just as good. That's my answer. Just use a label. I got lucky this time but if I really needed those events on a TextBox I'd be in trouble.

Comment: I do appreciate the comment from @DmitryBychenko but it's getting a lot of upvotes and I would like to remind everyone that it doesn't answer the question and doesn't provide a viable alternative. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enabled` doesn't really do anything in Windows Forms itself. It is a property of windows controls in general that a disabled window doesn't receive input messages (such as mouse events and keyboard events). So no, there is no way for you to disable a control and still receive those messages. Windows just don't work that way on Windows. It's not the `TextBox` control filtering those messages away - they don't come in the first place.

`TextBox` is a great wrapper around a windows common control. When you do something like `tbx.Text = "Hello";`, the `TextBox` just sends a message to that common control, saying "change the text to Hello". If you want to change that, you need to make the control essentially from scratch. You can make some hack that reverts whatever the common control does as response to a mouse event, but these usually don't work very well and tend to break down in unexpected ways.

In practice, what you really want is probably to tweak either the way `ReadOnly` behaves (e.g. disabling focus as well as making the control read only, but that's again just a dirty hack), or replace the `TextBox` with a control that can either be a control or a label - allowing you to switch between the two. If you want the text box to stop behaving as a text box, stop it from *being* a text box. Problem solved :)

I'd still reconsider using `ReadOnly`, though. Are you sure the user would *not* want to select text in the text box and copy it somewhere else? Or change the reading order?

Comment: It was really just a display widget. I wasn't sure how borders would look on a label but if you give a label a border it looks pretty much the same as a disabled TextBox but it can still receive events. I was just surprised because I'm more used to html/javascript where the disabled attribute doesn't necessarily prevent events from being raised.